# Is there a way to retrieve table identifier in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

ALL,

`SELECT object_name, object_id FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = '<table_name>';` does not produce anything.

`SELECT object_name, object_id FROM user_objects WHERE object_name = '<table_name>';` also does not produce anything.

Is there a way?

TIA!

Comment: pay attention  to upper/lower case: if not differently specified by double quotes, all object names are uppercase

Answer (score 0):

By default, in Oracle, object names are in uppercase, e.g.

```
select ... from all_objects where object_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

If someone created objects using mixed case (which means that they used double quotes), then you have to reference those objects using the same letter case, again enclosed into double quotes.

In your case: see whether this helps (note the `UPPER` function):

```
select ... from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: but why simple `SELECT * FROM <table_name>;` works just fine?

Comment: Because Oracle did it that way. When referencing objects, you can use **any letter case** you want, **unless** you created those objects (tables, views, procedures, column names, ...) using double quotes + mixed case.